# Wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to find the feature in WordPress 3.3.1 to add a page template. I am adding an archive but when I go into pages->Add New-> I get no option in the sidebar to use the existing archives.php file I want to use. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cool ill move it to there. Thanks anyways

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try on [Wordpress Stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) for Wordpress things.

Wordpress Codex is the best source for what you need, just check that :

[Page Templates Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

Answer (score 0):

Open the archives.php file and check if the file has on top of it the sentence "Template Name: ..." between comments. Otherwise add the following at the beginning of the file:

```
/* Template Name: Archives */
```

After that you should see the "Archives" option in the template drop-down when editing a page.